# Ti-Basic (Ti-84 Plus) What's that: »Real(12,Str1,Str2)→Str3« and how to make it work?

Tags: ti-basic

So there is this Calculator my teacher gave me to try to fix a program that worked in a previous version (probably the Ti-83). According to her it should give the derivation of an equation. The input is self-explaining and the rest of the code is rather simple:

```
PROGRAM:DER
:Input "EQUATION:",Str1
:Input "VAR:",Str2
:Real(12,Str1,Str2)→Str3
:Real(19,Str3
:
:
```

So now I'm somewhat freaked out by that `Real(` token there, because the catalog only lists `Real` and `real(`, where the last one only takes one argument.

So my question is: What the f*ck is that and how did it work?? Also, of course, do you have any idea how I can make a program calculating the derivation for the Ti-84 Plus? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's for the Symbolic parser hook if you also have Omnicalc installed. [Symbolic](http://www.detachedsolutions.com/symbolic/) is an app that provides (among other things) symbolic differentiation. It interfaces with BASIC using a parser hook (and a token hook to change how you see it on the screen), meaning that when a `real(` is encountered, it will look at what comes after it and intercept it if it's clear you're not trying to get the real part of a complex number. It's shown as `real(` if you also have Omnicalc installed, otherwise it should show as `d(` and so on (matching how it looks in the menu, accessed with [math][math]). Symbolic and Omnicalc both use the parser hook, which would normally pose a problem, but Omnicalc knows about Symbolic and "chains" the hooks.

`real(12` (aka `d(`) is for symbolic differentiation.

`real(19` (aka `pretty(`) probably prettifies a formula, it only works if you also have the Pretty Print app installed.

Comment: Wow. So what would you suggest me to do? Pass Omnicalc and Symbolic and Pretty Print to my teachers calculator?

Comment: @PeterNerlich yes, especially Symbolic, you could make it work with just that